# {Error] ambiguous overload for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream}' and 'const int')

Tags: c++

Soy nuevo en C++ y al realizar este código me sale siempre el mismo error, el código consiste en que le pida al usario cuántas filas y cuántas columnas quiere para una matriz bidimensional para después pedir los números y mostrarla en pantalla.

El error es este : {Error] ambiguous overload for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream}' and 'const int')

El código es este:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "iostream"
#include "stdlib.h"

using namespace std;

const int OU = 0; //Se declara una constante de tipo entero (Hay que recordar que estos se necesitaran para la declaración del arreglo)
const int UU = 0;
float matriz[OU] [UU]; //Se declara un arreglo de dos dimensiones
int fila, col; //Se declaran dos variables las cuales serán usadas para localizar las filas y las columnas

void leerarray(); //Declaración de la función para leer el arreglo
void imprimirarray(); //Declaración de la función para realizar la impresión del arreglo

int main()
{
    cout<<"INGRESAR LA CANTIDAD DE FILAS QUE QUIERE"<<endl;
    cin >> OU;
    cout<<"INGRESAR LA CANTIDAD DE COLUMNAS QUE QUIERE"<<endl;
    cin >> UU;
    leerarray(); //Se llama la función de leer arreglo
    cout << endl; //EL endl se utiliza para hacer un salto de línea, lo que también podemos hacer con \n, para ejemplificar se utilizarán ambas
    cout << "*****************MATRIZ*****************" << endl; //Se imprime un texto en consola
    imprimirarray(); //Se llama la función para hacer la impresión del array
}

void leerarray()
{
    fila = 0, col = 0;
    for(fila = 0; fila < OU; ++fila)
    {
        for(col = 0; col < UU; ++col)
        {
             cout << "Introduca los valores para Fila: " << fila << " - Columna: " << col << " = "; //Se pide al usuario que ingrese el valor para la fila y columna indicada
             cin >> matriz[fila][col]; //Se realiza la lectura desde teclado (nótese que en los corchetes, al igual que en los ciclos for, primero se pone la fila y después la columna)
         }
         cout << endl; //Se imprime un salto de línea
    }
}

/* NOTA: para leer un arreglo de dos dimensiones necesitamos dos ciclos for, el primero de utilizará para avanzar en las FILAS y el segundo se utilizará para las COLUMNAS */

void imprimirarray()
{
     fila = 0, col = 0;
     for(fila = 0; fila < OU; ++fila)
     {
          for(col = 0; col < UU; ++col)
          {
               if(col == 0) //Condicional if utilizada para comprobar si el valor es de la primera coumna de cada fila, esto para poder agregar un detalle visual al inicio
               {
                    cout << "| " << matriz[fila][col] << " | "; //Se imprime el valor de la fila y columna indicado
               }
               else //Si no se cumnple la condición del if (que sea el valor de la primera columna de cada fila), se realizan estas operaciones
               {
                    cout << matriz[fila][col] << " | ";
               }
          }
          cout << endl;
     }
}
```

Comment: Si usas `const`, esas variables no se pueden modificar después.

Comment: Ya intente quitándolo, pero si hago eso me sale otro error en el que dice que ocupo una const para los arreglos

Comment: Ya hice una modificación y ahora me salen estos dos errores:
1. [Warning] capture of variable 'OU' with non-automatic storage duration




2. [Error] expected '{' before ';' token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la línea 18 estás intentando leer un dato utilizando `cin >> OU;`, pero `OU` está declarad más arriba como constante utilizando `const int OU = 0;`. Igual sucede un poco más abajo con `UU`.

He realizado una modificación de tu código incluyendo variables para que el usuario pueda introducir las dimensiones de la matriz y he modificado las funciones para que tomen esas dimensiones como entrada.

Las constantes `OU` y `UU` ahora definirán las dimensiones máximas de la matriz. Deberás ajustarla a tus necesidades, o utilizar una reserva de memoria dinámica para la matriz, pero eso es tema para otro momento más adelante.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "iostream"
#include "stdlib.h"

using namespace std;

const int OU = 10; //Se declara una constante de tipo entero (Hay que recordar que estos se necesitaran para la declaración del arreglo)
const int UU = 10;
float matriz[OU] [UU]; //Se declara un arreglo de dos dimensiones
int fila, col; //Se declaran dos variables las cuales serán usadas para localizar las filas y las columnas

void leerarray(int ou, int uu); //Declaración de la función para leer el arreglo
void imprimirarray(int ou, int uu); //Declaración de la función para realizar la impresión del arreglo

int main()
{
    int ou, uu;
    cout<<"INGRESAR LA CANTIDAD DE FILAS QUE QUIERE"<<endl;
    cin >> ou;
    // TODO: aquí faltará comprobar que ou sea menor que OU.
    cout<<"INGRESAR LA CANTIDAD DE COLUMNAS QUE QUIERE"<<endl;
    cin >> uu;
    // TODO: aquí faltará comprobar que uu sea menor que UU.
    leerarray(ou, uu); //Se llama la función de leer arreglo
    cout << endl; //EL endl se utiliza para hacer un salto de línea, lo que también podemos hacer con \n, para ejemplificar se utilizarán ambas
    cout << "*****************MATRIZ*****************" << endl; //Se imprime un texto en consola
    imprimirarray(ou, uu); //Se llama la función para hacer la impresión del array
}

void leerarray(int ou, int uu)
{
    fila = 0, col = 0;
    for(fila = 0; fila < ou; ++fila)
    {
        for(col = 0; col < uu; ++col)
        {
             cout << "Introduca los valores para Fila: " << fila << " - Columna: " << col << " = "; //Se pide al usuario que ingrese el valor para la fila y columna indicada
             cin >> matriz[fila][col]; //Se realiza la lectura desde teclado (nótese que en los corchetes, al igual que en los ciclos for, primero se pone la fila y después la columna)
         }
         cout << endl; //Se imprime un salto de línea
    }
}

/* NOTA: para leer un arreglo de dos dimensiones necesitamos dos ciclos for, el primero de utilizará para avanzar en las FILAS y el segundo se utilizará para las COLUMNAS */

void imprimirarray(int ou, int uu)
{
     fila = 0, col = 0;
     for(fila = 0; fila < ou; ++fila)
     {
          for(col = 0; col < uu; ++col)
          {
               if(col == 0) //Condicional if utilizada para comprobar si el valor es de la primera coumna de cada fila, esto para poder agregar un detalle visual al inicio
               {
                    cout << "| " << matriz[fila][col] << " | "; //Se imprime el valor de la fila y columna indicado
               }
               else //Si no se cumnple la condición del if (que sea el valor de la primera columna de cada fila), se realizan estas operaciones
               {
                    cout << matriz[fila][col] << " | ";
               }
          }
          cout << endl;
     }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, me pondré a analizar el código para ver si logro comprender lo que hiciste. De verdad muchas gracias :D

Comment: No hay de qué. Si encuentras útil la respuesta y es correcta, puedes marcarla y así otros podrán también utilizarla, o sugerir la corrección necesaria a través de otra respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Esta bien, ya lo hice. Gracias de nuevo :D